# Intellij IDEA - How to debug browserify script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, intellij-idea

I have PlayFramework project in Intellij which is REST backend for page. 
I am also developing Frontend part in same project, but different folders - its react.js app and I am running gulp file to compile it with babel and then pack everything into bundle.js with browerify.

```
var bundler = watchify(browserify('./frontend/app.jsx', { debug: true }).transform(babel, {

    presets: ["es2015","react","stage-3"],
    plugins: [
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-runtime"
    ]
}));
```

I am able to see that there are maps created with bundle.js.
I am able to use chrome debugger for debugging in original files, but I am not able to setup debugger in Intellij. If I run debugger in Intellij using chrome extension I only get output from javascript terminal into it , but debugger does not stop at any breakpoints.

To setup javascript debugging I followed this steps:

1. Installed chrome extension
2. In Intellij I went to Run->Edit configuration
3. Added new JavaScript Debug configuration , with URL:
   http://localhost:9000/ and broswer Default(chrome) , I also tried to
   add path to frontend folder with all jsx files but it did not help
   either.

What DID i miss?